# Retrieve Facebook Account Information in ios 6

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, account

i want retrieve the information of a facebook account on the ios 6 integrated Facebook, now i do it in this way and i can retrieve only the username:

```
ACAccountType *accountTypeF = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeF];

            ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
            if (facebookAccount.username) {
}
}
}];
```

i want know how i can retrieve also the Name and Surname of the account and the pic of the user...anyone can help me?

Comment: you must checkmark at least one of the answers below!!!

Answer (score 8):

Jeffrey is right. Go to this post: [Facebook iOS 6 - get user info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904079/facebook-ios-6-get-user-info) and implement 2 methods given by Daniel.

After then make sure to make some changes in your application settings on `facebook developer account`.

- On main settings page disable `sandbox mode`
- Put your applications `bundle id`
- `Enable` facebook login

Then go to `Advance` settings on the left

- Select `Native/Desktop` as `App Type`
- make sure `App secret in client` is `NO`

Save all settings and it really takes few minutes to populate the changes on server. Finally **`Must reset you simulator`**

Answer (score 1):

`ACAccount` is a generic "social" class provided by Apple; it has only limited account information and no knowledge of Facebook data. After obtaining the account, you can instantiate an `SLRequest` to query the Facebook Graph API, using the account to authenticate it...

```
NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

SLRequest* request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                              URL:URL
                                       parameters:nil];

[request setAccount:account]; // Authentication - Requires user context

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData* responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse, NSError* error) {
  // parse the response or handle the error
}];
```