# Facebook iOS 6 - get user info

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

Is it possible to use the built-in iOS 6 Facebook integration to get the user's basic info (email address, birthday, etc)? All of the documentation/examples I have seen use the iOS 6 integration to simply open an `SLComposeViewController`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please check out my sample project. It allows you to upload video to Facebook, but it also includes a method to get your info, you should look at the file `ViewController.m`, the one noted "Native" in the tab controller.

https://bitbucket.org/danielphillips/fb-video-upload

You will need to import the `Social` and `Accounts` frameworks to do what you want. You request access to the users Facebook account from the `ACAccountStore`, if you are granted access, then you use this account to create an `SLRequest` with the parameters you want, here you want the graph object "/me".

Properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ACAccountStore *accountStore;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ACAccount *facebookAccount;
```

Authenticate:

```
- (IBAction)getMeButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(!_accountStore)
        _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                           options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"483616868329082", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if(granted){
                                                NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                                _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                                NSLog(@"Success");

                                                [self me];
                                            }else{
                                                // ouch
                                                NSLog(@"Fail");
                                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                            }
                                        }];
}
```

Get "me":

```
- (void)me{
    NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

    SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook 
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET 
                                                        URL:meurl 
                                                 parameters:nil];

    merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

    [merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", meDataString);

    }];

}
```

Comment: I used upper code the code first time works fine for me. But next time when I unlinked the fb account and then again linked then getting below errors {
    error =     {
        code = 190;
        message = "The access token was invalidated on the device.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
}

Comment: @NSIllusion did you solve the problem of the access token here?

Comment: @user717452 Almost solved but did not finding any good answer looking wired to me. My problem solved by resetting simulator content and settings.

Comment: Working well. If not then follow my answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539549/retrieve-facebook-account-information-in-ios-6/15946067#15946067

Comment: try the correct answer of this link. it worked for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601191/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-validating-access-token

Comment: how do ou get the user picture using SLRequest?
URL = https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?height=512&width=512 is not working

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jonasman/JNFacebookDownload

```
 self.facebookDownload = [JNFacebookDownload new];
 self.facebookDownload.appID = @"380637545425915";

[self.facebookDownload downloadInformation:^(NSDictionary *userInfo, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (error)
        {
            if (error.code == JNFacebookDownloadNoAccount)
                NSLog(@"No account");
            else if (error.code == JNFacebookDownloadNoPermissions)
                NSLog(@"No permissions");
            else if (error.code == JNFacebookDownloadNoAPPID)
                NSLog(@"No APP ID Configured");
        }
        else
        {
            self.textView.text = [userInfo description];
        }
    });
```