# Login with Facebook using SocialFramework

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, social-framework

I want perform a login using Facebook credential. This is possible using Facebook SDK with this step:

1. Create a Facebook App on facebook.developer.com
2. Import Facebook SDK in Xcode
3. Use Facebook SDK to perform login (this action open Facebook application on iPhone, and after it re-opens my application)

I would avoid open Facebook app and perform login inside my app, like Pinterest.

Using SocialFramework is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The latest Facebook SDK logs in using the FB account defined in system settings if available and falls back to Facebook app and/or website if not.

Comment: Ok, but as I write, I would like to know if it is possible with SocialFramework, not with Facebook SDK.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, what I meant was that Facebook SDK already uses SocialFramework to login when available. If you'd prefer not to use Facebook SDK at all, that's possible as well. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904079/facebook-ios-6-get-user-info