# Getting email from facebook user info

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Using this methods [Facebook iOS 6 - get user info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904079/facebook-ios-6-get-user-info) I can get the profile user info from Facebook, but in the json file are not retrieving the email of the user.

Can you helpme to get the email??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get email in this way:

```
[user objectForKey:@"email"]//Where user is FBGraphUser type
```

Here is the implementation when login is successful

```
case FBSessionStateOpen: {

            NSLog(@"accessToken: %@", session.accessTokenData.accessToken);
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
               NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     //error
                 }else{
                     NSLog(@"%@, %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"], user.description);

                 }
             }];
        }
         break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:[self _APP_KEY] andDelegate:self]; 
[facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",nil]];
```