# iOS - getting user's Facebook profile picture

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to get user's profile picture from Facebook in my app. I am aware of the http request that returns the profile picture:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER-ID/picture?type=small
```

But for that I need the user-id of my user.
Is there a way to fetch that from somewhere without using the Facebook SDK?
If not, can someone show me a simple way to get the user's id (or the profile picture)?

Comment: But there must be a user identifier right? How would your code magically knows that you need the profile picture of XYZ user? Second thing , the url that you've mentioned is not using any SDK, its a simple URL!

Comment: I know that the url is just a simple url (that's the reason I like it). I thought that maybe the iPhone can know the user-id if the Facebook application is installed on it.

Comment: r u get in the user profile ID

Comment: The user ID is the same as their FB Username, including any numbers, which you would need to locate them on FB anyway!

Comment: I know I can ask the user to put in his user name, and the app will perform this request. I wanted to find out if there's a way the iPhone already knows the user name.

Answer (score 9):

try this... it's working fine in my code ..  and without facebook id you cant get ..

and one more thing you can also pass your facebook username there..

```
 //facebookID = your facebook user id or facebook username both of work well
NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]]; 
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
UIImage *fbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But where do you get the facebookID from?

Comment: it'll get from facebook sdk and you can also use your facebook username there ...

Comment: So with this way I have to use the Facebook SDK?

Comment: yes ... using facebook sdk get facebook id and use .. It's working fine because I used this before 2-3 days..

Comment: Could you please explain how do I get the Facebook id using the Facebook sdk?

Comment: no, I don't use Facebook login. But I have the Facebook framework in my app.

Comment: use this link and first do facebook login .. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Comment: Do I have to use Facebook login in order to fetch the Facebook use id automatically?

Comment: I see that, but I don't want to login with Facebook. Can I still get it automatically?

Comment: Sorry, you need to facebook login fot this

Answer (score 1):

For getting FacebookId of any user, you will have to integrate Facebook Sdk from where you need to open session allow user to login in to Facebook (If user is already logged in to Facebook app, then it will just take permission from user to get access of the permission). Once you does that, you will get user details of logged in user from where you can get his FacebookId.

For more details please check developers.facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the profile picture you need to know the Facebook user ID of the user. This can be obtained logging into Facebook with `Social.framework` (if you don't want to use Facebook SDK).

You can use `ACAccountStore` to request access to user's Facebook account like this:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                       options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: YOUR_APP_ID_KEY, ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                        ...
```

Please refer to instructions already answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904079/facebook-ios-6-get-user-info).

For information regarding how to obtain a Facebook App ID key (YOUR_APP_ID_KEY), look at *Step 3* in this [article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

Though it's an older question, the same you can do with iOS SDK 4.x like:

**Swift:**

```
    let pictureRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture?type=large&redirect=false", parameters: nil)
    pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection, result, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("\(result)")
        } else {
            println("\(error)")
        }
    })
```

**Objective-C:**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/picture?type=large&redirect=false"]
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
    if (!error){
       NSLog(@"result: %@",result);}
    else {
       NSLog(@"result: %@",[error description]);
     }}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=picture&access_token=[yourAccessToken]

if your token is abcdef
then url will be:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=picture&access_token=acbdef

According to API explorer

you can use this link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dpicture&version=v2.4

then if you want to get code for any platform make this:

go to the end of page and press "Get Code" button

[image]

then in appeared dialog choose your platform

[image]

and you will see the code

Answer (score 0):

The following solution gets both essential user information and full size profile picture in one go...
The code uses latest Swift SDK for Facebook(facebook-sdk-swift-0.2.0), integrated on Xcode 8.3.3

import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

```
@IBAction func loginByFacebook(_ sender: Any) {

     let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile] , viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")

            let authenticationToken = accessToken.authenticationToken
            UserDefaults.standard.set(authenticationToken, forKey: "accessToken")

            let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
            connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me" , parameters : ["fields" : "id, name, picture.type(large)"])) { httpResponse, result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    print("Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
                /* Graph Request Succeeded: GraphResponse(rawResponse: Optional({
                 id = 10210043101335033;
                 name = "Sachindra Pandey";
                 picture =     {
                 data =         {
                 "is_silhouette" = 0;
                 url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13731659_10206882473961324_7366884808873372263_n.jpg?oh=f22b7c0d1c1c24654d8917a1b44c24ad&oe=5A32B6AA";
                 };
                 };
                 }))
                */

                    print("response : \(response.dictionaryValue)")



                case .failed(let error):
                print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
                }
            }
            connection.start()
        }
    }
}
```